# Partition columns to Athena Iceberg table with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, terraform-provider-aws

I would like to create an Iceberg table with partition columns with Terraform. This is possible with python/boto3 by running SQL DDL statements, but I have not found a way to do this with Terraform. My module currently iterates over a local variable that contains configurations for multiple tables:

```
resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "iceberg" {
  for_each = local.table_configs

  name          = each.value.table_name
  database_name = var.database_name
  table_type    = "EXTERNAL_TABLE"

  storage_descriptor {
    location = "s3://${var.bucket_id}/${each.value.table_name}/"
    
    dynamic "columns" {
      for_each = each.value.table_schema
      content {
        comment    = lookup(columns.value, "Comment", "")
        name       = columns.value["Name"]
        parameters = lookup(columns.value, "Parameters", null)
        type       = columns.value["Type"]
      }
    }
  }
  open_table_format_input {
    iceberg_input {
      metadata_operation = "CREATE"
      version            = "2"
    }
  }
}
```

The terraform provider makes the Hive style partition possible through `partition_keys` argument, but these cannot be used for making Iceberg partitions. Is there a way get an actual Iceberg partition columns to the table, perhaps through either `parameters` argument or by adding something to the table schemas? I feel that without partitions I am loosing a significant part of the benefits for my use case, which needs to scale well to large amounts of data.